# after using DI my websocket connection is crashing (signalR)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, signalr

after i add DI to my MainHub connection is established and after it crashed.

this is JS:

```
const localConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/mainhub")
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
    .withAutomaticReconnect([0, 10, 30, 60, 90, 150])
    .build();

async function start() {
    try {
        await connection.start();
        console.log("SIGNALR connected with NANO SERWER");
        await localConnection.start();
        console.log("LOCAL signalR connection established.")
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        setTimeout(start, 35000);
    }
};
connection.onclose(async () => {
    await start();
});
// Start the connection.
start();
```

and this is my MainHub (not crashing):

```
public class MainHub : Hub<IMainHub>
{
    public async Task ConnectionState(string isConnected)
    {
        await Clients.All.ConnectionState(isConnected);
       
    }
}
```

and this is one which is crashing after connection:

```
public class MainHub : Hub<IMainHub>
{
    private readonly ReadingsModel _readings;
    public MainHub(ReadingsModel readings)
    {
        _readings= readings;
    }
    public async Task ConnectionState(string isConnected)
    {
        await Clients.All.ConnectionState(isConnected);
      
    }
}
```

do you have any ideas why?

Comment: Do the transport logs tell you anything? The hub is a singleton so if ReadingsModel contains any dependencies that are transient or scoped, that may be the problem.

Comment: ReadingsModel is a PageModel class and this is problem. I need to work it around.